Error [SQLSTATE] 07002 > 0 [code]> 0 [2] > [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 07002 [SQLSTATE] => 07002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error ) )

<?php
include("database.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Server Application</title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .form-group {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    h2{
        text-align:center;
    }
    label {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    body{
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    h5{
      text-align:center;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h2><br>Server Application Setup</h2>
<!--App-->
<div class="container mt-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form method="POST" action="save_server.php">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Application_Name">Application Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Application_Name" name="Application_Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Application_Code">Application Code:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Application_Code" name="Application_Code">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Environment">Environment:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="Environment" name="Environment">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="DEV" id="Environment" name="Environment">DEV</option>
            <option value="PRD" id="Environment" name="Environment">PRD</option>
            <option value="UAT" id="Environment" name="Environment">UAT</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="CBC_Business_Unit">CBC Business Unit:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="CBC_Business_Unit" name="CBC_Business_Unit">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Credit & Collections Group" id="CBC_Business_Unit" name="CBC_Business_Unit">Credit & Collections Group</option>
            <option value="CBC CIB" id="CBC_Business_Unit" name="CBC_Business_Unit">CBC CIB</option>
            <option value="CBC LOS" id="CBC_Business_Unit" name="CBC_Business_Unit">CBC LOS</option> 
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Provisoning_Date">Provisoning Date:</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="Provisoning_Date" name="Provisoning_Date">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Subscription">Subscription:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Subscription" name="Subscription">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Storage_Account">Storage Account:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Storage_Account" name="Storage_Account">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Private_Endpoint">Private Endpoint:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Private_Endpoint" name="Private_Endpoint">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Network_Virtual_Appliance1">Network Virtual Appliance:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Network_Virtual_Appliance1" name="Network_Virtual_Appliance1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Network_Virtual_Appliance2">Network Virtual Appliance:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Network_Virtual_Appliance2" name="Network_Virtual_Appliance2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="HO_S2S_VPN_GW">HO S2S VPN GW:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="HO_S2S_VPN_GW" name="HO_S2S_VPN_GW">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="HO_ExpressRoute_GW">HO ExpressRoute GW:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="HO_ExpressRoute_GW" name="HO_ExpressRoute_GW">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Enable_Diagnostic_Settings">Enable Diagnostic Settings:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Enable_Diagnostic_Settings" name="Enable_Diagnostic_Settings">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="Remarks">Remarks:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Remarks" name="Remarks" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Remarks1" class="form-label">Remarks</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Remarks1" name="Remarks1" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Remarks2">Remarks</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Remarks2" name="Remarks2" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
</div>



<h5>"Resource Groups"</h5>
<!-- Resource Group Form -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="RG_Name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RG_Name" name="RG_Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="Resource_Group_Region" class="form-label">Region</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="Resource_Group_Region" name="Resource_Group_Region">
            <option value="" id="Resource_Group_Region" name="Resource_Group_Region"></option>
            <option value="Southeast Asia" id="Resource_Group_Region" name="Resource_Group_Region">Southeast Asia</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="RG_Description">Description</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RG_Description" name="RG_Description">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    

<!--Virtual Networks-->
<h5>"Virtual Networks"</h5>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="VN_Name" class="form-label">Virtual Networks Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="VN_Name" name="VN_Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="VN_Subscription" class="form-label">Subscription</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="VN_Subscription" name="VN_Subscription">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Resource_Group" class="form-label">Resource Group</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Resource_Group" name="Resource_Group">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="VN_Region" class="form-label">Region</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="VN_Region" name="VN_Region">
          <option value="" id="VN_Region" name="VN_Region"></option>
          <option value="Southeast Asia" id="VN_Region" name="VN_Region">Southeast Asia</option>
          <option value="" id="VN_Region" name="VN_Region"></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Address_space" class="form-label">Address Space</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address_space" name="Address_space">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Custom_DNS_Servers" class="form-label">Custom DNS Servers</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Custom_DNS_Servers" name="Custom_DNS_Servers">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="register">Register</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
  }
</script>
    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




<?php
$serverName = "003ENGGSU03\SQLEXPRESS01";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => "SERVER",
    "Uid" => "",
    "PWD" => "" 
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

if ($conn === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Check if the form is submitted
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{ 
    // Retrieve DATA
    // Application 
    $Application_Name = $_POST['Application_Name'];
    $Application_Code = $_POST['Application_Code'];
    $Environment = $_POST['Environment'];
    $CBC_Business_Unit = $_POST['CBC_Business_Unit'];
    $Provisoning_Date = $_POST['Provisoning_Date'];
    $Subscription = $_POST['Subscription'];
    $Storage_Account = $_POST['Storage_Account'];
    $Private_Endpoint = $_POST['Private_Endpoint'];
    $Network_Virtual_Appliance1 = $_POST['Network_Virtual_Appliance1'];
    $Network_Virtual_Appliance2 = $_POST['Network_Virtual_Appliance2'];
    $HO_S2S_VPN_GW = $_POST['HO_S2S_VPN_GW'];
    $HO_ExpressRoute_GW = $_POST['HO_ExpressRoute_GW'];
    $Enable_Diagnostic_Settings = $_POST['Enable_Diagnostic_Settings'];
    $Remarks = $_POST['Remarks'];
    $Remarks1 = $_POST['Remarks1'];
    $Remarks2 = $_POST['Remarks2'];



    //Resource Groups
    $RG_Name = $_POST['RG_Name'];
    $Resource_Group_Region = $_POST['Resource_Group_Region'];
    $RG_Description = $_POST['RG_Description'];



    //Virtual Networks
    $VN_Name = $_POST['VN_Name'];
    $VN_Subscription = $_POST['VN_Subscription'];
    $Resource_Group = $_POST['Resource_Group'];
    $VN_Region = $_POST['VN_Region'];
    $Address_space = $_POST['Address_space'];
    $Custom_DNS_Servers = $_POST['Custom_DNS_Servers'];


    // Application
    $sql = "INSERT INTO App (Application_Name, Application_Code, Environment, CBC_Business_Unit, Provisoning_Date, Subscription, Storage_Account, Private_Endpoint, Network_Virtual_Appliance1, Network_Virtual_Appliance2, HO_S2S_VPN_GW, HO_ExpressRoute_GW, Enable_Diagnostic_Settings, Remarks, Remarks1, Remarks2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $params = array($Application_Name, $Application_Code, $Environment, $CBC_Business_Unit, $Provisoning_Date, $Subscription, $Storage_Account, $Private_Endpoint, $Network_Virtual_Appliance1, $Network_Virtual_Appliance2, $HO_S2S_VPN_GW, $HO_ExpressRoute_GW, $Enable_Diagnostic_Settings, $Remarks, $Remarks1, $Remarks2);
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $params);

    if ($stmt === false) 
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    if (sqlsrv_execute($stmt) === false) 
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    echo "Data inserted into 'Application successfully.<br>";



    //Resource Groups
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Resource_Groups (RG_ID, RG_Name, Resource_Group_Region, RG_Description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $params = array($RG_Name, $Resource_Group_Region, $RG_Description);    
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $params);

    if ($stmt === false) 
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    if (sqlsrv_execute($stmt) === false) 
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    echo "Data inserted into 'Resource Groups' successfully.<br>";
    


    //Virtual Networks
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Virtual_Networks (VN_ID, VN_Name, VN_Subscription, Resource_Group, VN_Region, Address_space, Custom_DNS_Servers) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $params = array($VN_Name, $VN_Subscription, $Resource_Group, $VN_Region, $Address_space, $Custom_DNS_Servers);    
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $params);

    if ($stmt === false) 
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    if (sqlsrv_execute($stmt) === false) 
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    echo "Data inserted into 'Virtual Network' successfully.<br>";


    sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
?>


I tried to delete all the tables to receive data and I tried one table, it was able to receive user input data and no error was experienced, but when I put two tables there appear the error

"Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 07002 [SQLSTATE] => 07002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error ) )"

